# Vaadin + Spring Integration: Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, vaadin

I have a Vaadin web application with UI class like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("mytheme")
public class LogsUI extends UI {

LogsView logsViewer = new LogsView();

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = LogsUI.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.setContent(logsViewer);
    panel.setSizeFull();
    setContent(panel);
}
}
```

As u can see i add use `setContent` to add LogsView class which is a view - it is a fragment of declaration:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LogsView extends CustomComponent implements View {

//some variables, buttons, components etc
ProcessDao processDao;


//sample method
void sampleMethod(){
      processDao = new ProcesDao;
      processDao.getAllprocesses(); //just sample, no matter about logic
}

}
```

My `ProcessDao` class:

```
public class ProcessDao {


@Autowired
ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration;

public ProcessDao() {
}


public List<ProcessEntity> getAllProcess(){
    System.out.println("TEST:" + applicationConfiguration);

    //entity manager and other stuffs

     return processList;
}
}
```

As u can see i did `System.out.println()` to check if im getting `applicationConfiguration` object. Im getting null. This is main problem.

this is my ApplicationConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sample.project"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:jpa.postgresql.properties", "classpath:hibernate.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.sample.project.repo"})
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${javax.persistence.jdbc.driver}")
private String driverClassName;

@Value("${javax.persistence.jdbc.url}")
private String databaseUrl;

@Value("${javax.persistence.jdbc.user}")
private String databaseUser;

@Value("${javax.persistence.jdbc.password}")
private String databasePassword;

@Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
private String dialect;

@Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
private boolean showSQL;

@Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
private String hbm2ddlAuto;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
@PersistenceContext
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateJPAProperties());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.sample.project");
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(databaseUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(databaseUser);
    dataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);
    return dataSource;
}

public Properties hibernateJPAProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", showSQL);
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddlAuto);
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public FinancialProcessEntityDao financialProcessEntityDao() {
    FinancialProcessEntityDao dao = new FinancialProcessEntityDao();
    return dao;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

}
```

Am i something missing? How to properly integrate my Vaadin app with Spring?

Comment: Can you post your `Beans.xml` file content ?

Comment: I'm not sure how Spring works so it's not an answer, but - it's not a problem with integration, it's Dependency Injection basics. You can't create an object with `new` and expect dependencies to work.

Comment: @Deltharis i belive your are right. However i would be grateful if u will point me how to fix it. I dont have many experience in this topic, this is my first try

Comment: @Zakaria Beans.xml is empty - as much i know it is no needed

Comment: I'll leave answering to Spring experts (I use EJB), I don't know configuration details required - however most probably the fact of vaadin integration has no bearing on those errors.

Comment: @Deltharis can u post some example how it would look like with EJB then? Spring is not a must in my project

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
processDao = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(
    VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext()).getBean(IProcessDao.class);
```

You can find some description here: [link](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring+Integration)

Comment: it fix null pointer exception however im getting new error: `No qualifying bean of type [com.sample.project.ProcessDao] is defined`

Comment: @ilovkatie Your `ProcessDao` should look something like this: `@Repository public class ProcessDao implements IProcessDao {...`

Comment: is my `IProcessDao` interface needs any annotations aswell?

Comment: @ilovkatie I don't think.